# reference element in a animate element and the element and animate element are in a defs to be reflected in use element

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I am researching svg animation and was wonder if it possible to use the href attribute in the animate element which the target of the href and the animate element it self are in a defs... here is a code working example:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 100">
    <defs>
        <rect id="anim-rect"
            x="-25" y="-25"
            width="50" height="50"
            fill="#29e" >
            <animate
                attributeName="fill"
                values="#29e; #4e4; #f40; #29e"
                dur="6s"
                repeatCount="indefinite" />
        </rect>
    </defs>

    <use xlink:href="#anim-rect" transform="translate(100 50)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#anim-rect" transform="translate(200 50)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#anim-rect" transform="translate(300 50)"/>
</svg>
```

And here what I want to do:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 100">
    <defs>
        <rect id="anim-rect"
            x="-25" y="-25"
            width="50" height="50"
            fill="#29e" >
        </rect>
        <animate xlink:href="#anim-rect"
                attributeName="fill"
                values="#29e; #4e4; #f40; #29e"
                dur="6s"
                repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </defs>

    <use xlink:href="#anim-rect" transform="translate(100 50)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#anim-rect" transform="translate(200 50)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#anim-rect" transform="translate(300 50)"/>
</svg>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the [SVG 2 spec](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#UseAnimations), this should work. If it doesn't, it must be considered a bug. That said, what is the downside to using implicit animation targeting (animate as child)? The `<animate>` element can only target one element, anyway, so it cannot be reused.

Comment: animate element can be reuse as shown in my question with the defs... It a shame when things should work and they don't...

Comment: [Quote](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#TargetElement): "<iri> must point to exactly one target element which is capable of being the target of the given animation."